# I need to trigger 1 request of Loop-2 on every 10 requests of Loop-1 in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to setup my jmeter requests such as,

Thread Group >> Loop-1 (which has 3000 requests) Now I want to Add one more loop in ThreadGroup which triggers one request after every 10 requests of Loop-1.

Ex. I need to perform 300 requests of Loop-2 along with 3000 requests of Loop-1. So when 10 Requests of Loop-1 triggers One Request of Loop-2 triggers.

What could be the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Put your `Loop-2` under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) and use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition:

```
${__groovy(((vars.get('__jm__Loop-1__idx') as int + 1) % 10) == 0,)}
```

Demo:

[image]